# Error en ubuntu: sistema de archivos de solo lectura

Tags: ubuntu

**Un saludo a la comunidad de software libre, mi problema es el siguiente:**

Cada vez que inserto una unidad usb, o cualquier medio extraible a mi laptop con ubuntu 16.04 Lts daña el sistema de archivos de mi disco duro retornando el siguiente mensaje: `Sistema de archivos de solo lectura` al momento de crear, modificar o eliminar ficheros en la partición  `/dev/sda`

Sin embargo esto lo puedo resolver aplicando un `sudo fsck /dev/sda2 -y`, pero tengo que reiniciar el equipo cada vez que hago eso.

Tal vez sea un error interno de mi HDD, no lo se. Les ruego alguna sugerencia para resolver esto. Gracias.

Comment: Ten un disco nuevo a mano para cuando `sudo fsck /dev/sda2 -y` deje de funcionar.

Comment: Realice un respaldo y cambie mi disco. Salu2

Comment: te consulto, cambiar el disco soluciono el problema? Estoy con el mismo problema, solo que no encuentro que es exactamente lo que detona el problema, me pasa aveces cuando se suspende o cuando la estoy usando